# Example on how to create HTML for THTMLViewer at runtime

Tags: delphi

With Delphi XE I've installed THTMLViewer. I see plenty of examples on how to read an HTM file (LoardFromFile) and display it in the Viewer. What I want to do is create the HTM at runtime in my program. If I had a RichEdit component I would have several SelText := lines.

Of course I can add lines to a stringlist, then SavetoFile the stringlist and finally LoadFromFile into htmlViewer, but that seems like an unnecessary extra step.

Is there a Memo.Lines or some other property of THtmlViewer where I can Add the desired lines of HTML coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a version of the component that supports it then `LoadFromString` would probably be the simplest function to use.

I am surprised that you didn't find that in the source.  As I seem to recall it being available for some time.

If you need a newer version of the component source you can find it here: [THTMLViewer Project](http://code.google.com/p/thtmlviewer/)